# Parameters to connect to Proximus Public Wi-Fi Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: wireless

What parameters should be used to connect via Proximus Public Wifi ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the parameters that works:

- Security : WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Authentication : Tunneled TLS
- No CA certificate is required : checked
- Inner authentication : PAP
- Username : your.user@proximuswifi.be
- Password : yourpassword

[image: Wifi Parameters]

Comment: Note : if the field "domain" is required, you can use the value ".isp.belgacom.be"